# x86 Assembly. Making my console output pretty

Tags: assembly

I am pretty new to programming in genreal, and I am having trouble figuring out how to display my results (numbers) in rows and columns instead of 1 per line, or spaced evenly.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can we get some code that you've written?

Comment: Im borrowing this from another page:   INCLUDE irvine32.inc


.data
msg byte "Genrating 50 number",0
.code
main PROC
mov edx,offset byte
call WriteString
call crlf
mov ecx,50
L1:
mov eax,+33
call RandomRange
call writeDec



exit
main ENDP
END main

Comment: Trying to get the output to align in columns and not just one per line, or whatnot

Answer (score 0):

Count the digits in each of your result (number), subtract the count from 12 and write that many spaces preceeding your number. Write new line (CRLF) after each sixth number. You should get your result formated into six columns, right aligned.